# Show Image A or B - Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

How can I display Image A on the user's screen if it is false or Image B if it is true, Image A is the first one that appears, when the user clicks on it, the state changes to true and switches to Image B, and switches once the user clicks on it, the state changes to true or false.
Image A = false
Image B = true

[image: Image A]
[image: Image B]


Image A - Image B

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  bool closedImage = false;
  bool openImage = true;
  bool switchOn = false;

  void _onSwitchChanged(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      switchOn = false;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: 
        Center(
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Switch(
                onChanged: _onSwitchChanged,
                value: switchOn,
              );
            },
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: ClipRRect(
                child: switchOn ? Image.asset('lib/assets/closed.png') : Image.asset('lib/assets/open.png')
              )
            ),
          ),
        )
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just toggle the switchOn variable like this:

```
void _onSwitchChanged(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      switchOn = !switchOn;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your method `_onSwitchChanged` needs to use the incoming bool value argument (which is supplied by the `Switch`).

Here's a similar example showing typical usage:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SwitchFieldPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SwitchFieldPageState createState() => _SwitchFieldPageState();
}

class _SwitchFieldPageState extends State<SwitchFieldPage> {
  bool switchVal = false;
  String monkey = 'A';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Switch Field'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Text('Monkey $monkey'),
              Switch(
                onChanged: (val) { // ← remember to use val (bool)
                  print('Switch value: $val');
                  setState(() {
                    switchVal = val; // this sets the Switch setting on/off
                    monkey = val ? 'B' : 'A';  // change your monkey source
                  });

                },
                value: switchVal,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, can you help me, I have been trying for 3 hours to solve this problem, and so far I have not succeeded, can I upload it on Github for you to help me? It's a project for my portfolio as a Front-end, thanks.

Comment: I tested your solution, it worked, but I wanted to use onTap instead of Switch, to avoid showing a button

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) or [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) to detect when the user presses on the image. For updating the image, I'd suggest learning [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options). To make this simple for now, we're going to use [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html).

`screen.dart`:

```
final ScreenBloc _screenBloc = ScreenBloc();

// This is inside your widget build
StreamBuilder<AuthState>(
          stream: _screenBloc.pic,
          initialData: false,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return GestureDetector(
                 onTap: ()=> _screenBloc.toggle(),
                 child: snapshot.data?Image.asset('lib/assets/closed.png') : Image.asset('lib/assets/open.png'),
              );
          },
)
```

`screen_bloc.dart`:

```
class ScreenBloc{
 bool _currentState=false;
 StreamController<bool> _picStream = StreamController<bool>();
 Stream<bool> get pic => _picStream.stream;
 void toggle(){
  _currentState=!_currentState;
  _picStream.add(_currentState);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to implement and study state management